# UILocalNotification nil userInfo

Tags: xcode4, ios4, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I try to cancel a Local notification. I attach a dict with a Id for locate it later:

```
+ (void) send:(NSString*)title actionText:(NSString *)actionText when:(NSDate *)when count:(NSInteger)count option:(NSDictionary *)options 
{
    UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    //Setup code here...
    notif.userInfo = options;
    ALog(@"Sending notification %@ %@", notif.alertBody, notif.userInfo);
    //Print: Sending notification Task Col 0 0 {id = "1-1"};

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
}
```

Then when I try to locate it:

```
+ (void) cancelNotification:(NSString *)theId {
    for(UILocalNotification *aNotif in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]) 
    {
        if([[aNotif.userInfo objectForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:theId])
        {
            // Never come here: userInfo is nil!!!
        }
    }
}
```

Always the userInfo is nil. I send the dict:

```
NSMutableDictionary *info = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [info setObject:theId forKey:@"id"];
```

or

```
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:theId forKey:@"id"]
```

with the same result. (theId is NSString)

Answer (score 0):

The local notification valid only, it has valid timestamp. So while you are creating make sure that, it has valid timestamp. So that, it will be present in scheduledNotifications of UIApplicaiton.

Please let me know your comments.

eg: localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];